# How to use a CTE to update a table - Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, common-table-expression, hue

I'm new to hive and trying to update a table (table_A) with a new column based on the values retrieved from another table (table_B). table_B is used as a lookup table for the categorical variable descriptions.

Ex: table_A

| index | field_x | field_y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | L | S |
| 2 | H | H |
| 3 | M | S |

Ex: table_B

| variable_name | variable_category | variable_category_description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| field_x | L | Low |
| field_x | M | Medium |
| field_x | H | High |
| field_y | S | Soft |
| field_y | H | Hard |

Based on the table_A and table_B I need to obtain following table.

| index | field_x | field_x_description | field_y | field_y_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | L | Low | S | Soft |
| 2 | H | High | H | Hard |
| 3 | M | Medium | S | Soft |

I tried following in hue hive editor just to add one column at the beginning. My editor does not support update statements.

```
CREATE TABLE table_C AS 
SELECT index,
    field_x, 
    field_y, 
(SELECT variable_category_description
    FROM table_B 
    where table_B.variable_name = 'field_x' and  table_B.variable_category= table_A.field_x
AS field_x_description
FROM table_A
```

I get following error

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 5:5 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'variable_category_description' 'FROM' in expression specification

A fix for this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two joins (INNER or LEFT) with table_B

```
CREATE TABLE table_C AS 
SELECT a.index,
       a.field_x, 
       x.variable_category_description AS field_x_description,
       a.field_y, 
       y.variable_category_description AS field_y_description
FROM table_A
     LEFT JOIN table_B x ON x.variable_name  = 'field_x' 
                        and x.variable_category = a.field_x

     LEFT JOIN table_B y ON y.variable_name  = 'field_y' 
                        and y.variable_category = a.field_y
;
```

Comment: This answer saved my day. Thank you